# React in WebPack

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I join JS-files through WebPack. In config introduced all files.

```
entry: ['./file1', './file2', 'react', 'react-dom']
```

React and React-dom downloaded through npm. If in file I call React, returns error:

```
ReferenceError: React is not defined
```

But if I write

```
import {React} from 'react';
```

returns error

```
TypeError: _react.React is undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be like,

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(...);
```

Answer (score 2):

React is exported as default, hence there is no need to import it using named imports.

This is **wrong**:

```
import {React} from 'react';
```

This is **correct**:

```
import React from 'react';
```

Read about ES6 module exports: http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html

Comment: i'll just add that if you want to load more "portions" of this module you can write it like this for example: `import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';`